# Keras - классификация текста - оверфиттинг, и как улучшить модель

Tags: нейронные-сети, keras, классификация

Я делаю нейронную сеть для классификации текста на русском языке по этим примерам - 
https://github.com/jiegzhan/multi-class-text-classification-cnn-rnn
https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

В учебном наборе у меня используется русский язык, однако в тексте много специфичских терминов, так что использовать заранее обученную модель word2vec не особо будет полезным.

Следующие параметры 
Максимальная длина статьи - 969 слов (в среднем значительно меньше), но мы добавляем PAD вместо пустых слов.
размер получающегося словаря - 53886
Колилчество классов - 12 ( и они к сожалению распределены очень неравномерно, например первый  класс содержит 5000 записий, а второй только 1500)

Также самая главная проблема - это размер учебного набора - 
Всего 9876 записей
И увеличить его к сожалению никак нельзя.

Вот мой код

```
x, x_test, y, y_test = train_test_split(x_, y_, test_size=0.1)
x_train, x_dev, y_train, y_dev = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)


embedding_vecor_length = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=7, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=9, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=12, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=15, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(200,dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3))
model.add(Dense(labels_count, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=30)
scores = model.evaluate(x_tеst, y_test)
```

Я пробовал разные параметры, и сеть вроде работает. 
Во время обучения получается очень большая тоночть (до 98%)
Но если проводить оценку - то максимум что я смог взять это было 74 процента (это были маленькие знаничения embedding_vecor_length, и batch_size)
Ну это явно оферфитинг..

Вопросы у меня такие 
1) Правильно ли я построил модель в приципе? Я просто не совсем понимаю как текстовые данные сохраняются при конволюции (все примеры в интернете про картинки)
Может мне нужно использовать одновременную конволюцию с разными размерами фильтров и потом их мержить?
Вообще расскажите как правильно делать конволюцию для текста и какие размеры фильтров выбирать?
(мне кажется что в первом слое filters=32, kernel_size=3 конволюцию происходит только по 96 слловам? Или я не прав? и он берет весь текст?)

2) Как Решить проблему с оверффитингом? У меня нет возможности увеличить дата сет..
Я уже добавил Dropout (кстати правильно ли?)

3) Может нужна совсем другая структура сети? Например - читсая RNN?

Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Очень сложно сказать, в чём причина оверфитинга, не видя примеров. Есть ссылки на данные? Те, что Вы указали, я так понимаю -- это примеры реализаций. Одинаковая ли у Вас предобработка текста на валидации и на трейне? Тексты берутся из одного источника? Вы их шафлите?